# How can I change the destination of a shared button?

Tags: reactjs

I have an info section on my website where I list several services and a "Learn More" button that when click currently takes the user back to the top of the page.

I would instead like each sections button to go to another page when clicked. The problem is that there is one button connected to all of the services.

Is there a way to change the destination of the button click for each HomeObj?

Thank you for the help!

Here is the code for the services in Data.js

```
export const homeObjOne = {
  id: "about",
  lightBg: false,
  lightText: true,
  lightTextDesc: true,
  topLine: "Mitchel LTD",
  headline: "Professional & Affordable Services",
  description:
    "We solve complex problems and take the worry out of your hands and off of your mind.",
  buttonLabel: "Get started",
  navToPage: "home",
  imgStart: false,
  img: require("../../images/scales.jpg"),
  alt: "North West Services",
  dark: true,
  primary: true,
  darkText: false,
};

export const homeObjTwo = {
  id: "services",
  lightBg: true,
  lightText: false,
  lightTextDesc: false,
  topLine: "FAQ",
  headline: "We're here to help!",
  description:
    "Have a question? Need an answer?",
  buttonLabel: "Learn More!",
  navToPage: "home",
  imgStart: true,
  img: require("../../images/split.jpg"),
  alt: "FAQ",
  dark: false,
  primary: false,
  darkText: true,
};
```

Here is the code for the button

```
import React from "react";
import { Button } from "../ButtonElements";

import {
  InfoContainer,
  InfoWrapper,
  InfoRow,
  Column1,
  Column2,
  TextWrapper,
  TopLine,
  Heading,
  Subtitle,
  BtnWrap,
  ImgWrap,
  Img,
} from "./infoElements";

const InfoSection = ({
  lightBg,
  id,
  imgStart,
  topLine,
  lightText,
  headline,
  darkText,
  description,
  buttonLabel,
  img,
  alt,
  primary,
  dark,
  dark2,
  navToPage,
}) => {
  return (
    <>
      <InfoContainer lightBg={lightBg} id={id}>
        <InfoWrapper>
          <InfoRow imgStart={imgStart}>
            <Column1>
              <TextWrapper>
                <TopLine>{topLine}</TopLine>
                <Heading lightText={lightText}>{headline}</Heading>
                <Subtitle darkText={darkText}>{description}</Subtitle>
                <BtnWrap>
                  <Button
                    to={navToPage}
                    smooth={true}
                    duration={500}
                    spy={true}
                    exact="true"
                    offset={-80}
                    primary={primary ? 1 : 0}
                    dark={dark ? 1 : 0}
                    dark2={dark2 ? 1 : 0}
                  >
                    {navToPage}
                    {buttonLabel}
                  </Button>
                </BtnWrap>
              </TextWrapper>
            </Column1>
            <Column2>
              <ImgWrap>
                <Img src={img} alt={alt} />
              </ImgWrap>
            </Column2>
          </InfoRow>
        </InfoWrapper>
      </InfoContainer>
    </>
  );
};

export default InfoSection;
```

Comment: you can alternate button's to="where" same way as done with `buttonLabel` value

Comment: @LironZ Would you be able to show me in code how to do that? 
I'm not sure how to implement that where I can have the button go to different pages

Comment: @LironZ Could you please show me how to change where the button sends the user when clicked?

Comment: currently the destination `to` is fixed value set to "home",
pointing you to `buttonLabel` was meant to make the connection between data property to the content of the button. apply the same on `to` atttribute  of the button `< button to="{navToPage}"` while `navToPage` is your new property in both data objects

Comment: @LironZ I see what you're saying! 

I've now made the following changes to the code but the button now just doesn't work. Could you explain where I've gone wrong?

I've added navToPage: "home", under buttonLabel on homeObjOne

and changed my to="home"  to "to="{navToPage}"

Now the button when clicked does nothing

Comment: can't see any changes :) pls update question

Comment: @LironZ Thank you for helping me! I made the edits to the question.

Comment: 1. `navToPage` is nmissin  from your component's function argument list.
2. replace `to={"navTo"}` with `to={navTo}` (remove the quotes)

Comment: @LironZ sorry where should I add navToPage?

Comment: lets get back to `buttonLabel`, where does it located? what path it takes from data object to page layout? we have established that navToPage should passed the same way `buttonLabel` is.

Comment: @LironZ 1. I placed navToPage: "home", under buttonLabel on Data.js homeObjOne but all that did was add home text to "Get started" it appeared as "homeGet started"

2.  I made this change "<Button  to={navToPage}"

There is a {buttonLabel} within the <Button> </Button> and I've added a {navToPage} above that.

Thanks for helping me with this!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244239/discussion-between-heretolearn-and-lironz).